# Ignore specific derived classes for .NET XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

Let's say we have a class `Root` that contains an array of an abstract class `BaseClass` that is implemented by 2 derived classes `Derived1` and `Derived2`

```
[XmlRootAttribute("root")]
public class Root
{
  [XmlElement("derived1", typeof(Derived1))]
//[XmlElement("derived2", typeof(Derived2))]
  public BaseClass[];
}

public abstract class BaseClass { }

public class Derived1 : BaseClass { }

public class Derived2 : BaseClass { }
```

How can i tell the XmlSerializer that instances of `Derived2` should be ignored during serialization?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding [XmlIgnore] to Derived2?

Comment: @Lloyd You can't put that on classes. Topic: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can

Comment: I tried a lot. Another thing is that in the above code, the XmlSerializer throws an Exception, that Derived2 is unkown. That is expected, but i can't find a way to continue serialization in that case without writing something about Derived2 in the XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wrong, there is: ShouldSerialize does the magic [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx) 
Assuming your property is "Obj"

```
public bool ShouldSerializeObj() {
      return Obj is Derived1;
   }
```

**Edit:**
If you want to take care of the serialization, you can implement IXmlSerializable interface as you said like this

```
public class Derived1 : BaseClass, IXmlSerializable 
{ 
  public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

  public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
  {
    reader.MoveToContent();
    Name = reader.GetAttribute("Name");
    reader.ReadStartElement();
    if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
    {
      YourProperty = reader.ReadElementString("YourElem");
      reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
  }

  public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
  {
    witer.WriteAttributeString("Name", Name);
    writer.WriteElementString("YourElem", "ThisIsMyContent");
  }
}
```

This way you can take care of the serialization. 
Note: The `GetSchema()` is supposed to return null

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. But the ShouldSerialize*PropertyName*() method only decides if a property is serialized or not. It's the same as the XmlIgnore attribute. It cannot decide on list elements of the property :(

Comment: oh so you want for each element of the array to be serialized or not? I'm afraid that is not possible. You'd have to implement your own serializer I guess...

Comment: Ok, my next idea was to implement the IXmlSerializable interface in Derived2 with **empty** ReadXml() and WriteXml(). I hoped that will work, but it results in an empty <derived2 /> in XML.